# How to send SMS messages from amazon sns to not verified numbers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have amazon sns set up to send SMS messages, but it only sends the messages to verified phone numbers. If I try to send SMS to unverified number, the message does not arrive.

I want to be able to send SMS to any number without verifying the number in the aws sns dashboard.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your AWS account is in the "SMS sandbox" that limits where you can send messages.

From [SMS sandbox - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sms-sandbox.html):

> When you start using Amazon SNS to send SMS messages, **your AWS account is in the SMS sandbox**. The SMS sandbox provides a safe environment for you to try Amazon SNS features without risking your reputation as an SMS sender. While your account is in the SMS sandbox, you can use all of the features of Amazon SNS, with the following restrictions:
>
> - You can send SMS messages **only to verified destination phone numbers**.
> - You can have up to 10 verified destination phone numbers.
> - You can delete destination phone numbers only after 24 or more hours have passed since verification or the last verification attempt.
>
> When your account is **moved out of the sandbox**, these restrictions are removed, and you can send SMS messages to any recipient.

To move out of the sandbox, [Moving out of the SMS sandbox - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sms-sandbox-moving-to-production.html) says:

> Moving your AWS account out of the SMS sandbox requires that you first add, verify, and test destination phone numbers. Then, you must **create a case with AWS Support**.
> ...
> On the Amazon SNS console's Mobile text messaging (SMS) page, under Account information, choose **Exit SMS sandbox**.
> ...
> The AWS Support team provides an initial response to your request within 24 hours.
>
> To prevent our systems from being used to send unsolicited or malicious content, we consider each request carefully. If we can, **we will grant your request within this 24-hour period**. However, if we need additional information from you, it might take longer to resolve your request.
>
> If your use case doesn't align with our policies, we might be unable to grant your request.