# AWS SNS service for text sms

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm using the AWS SNS service for text messages to new users, and a welcome email, currently AWS sends messages to verified phone numbers only but I want to send them to non-verified and un-subscribed users too how can I achieve that? I'm using a node.js server of this one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve amazon sns sms send to only verified numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76834825/how-to-solve-amazon-sns-sms-send-to-only-verified-numbers)

Comment: It is also described in the AWS Compute Blog article [Introducing the SMS sandbox for Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-sms-sandbox-for-amazon-sns/) how AWS accounts are placed in the SMS sandbox by default, where you can send SMS messages only to verified recipients.  The article further states: "[...] request to leave the SMS sandbox by contacting AWS Support. As part of your request, you must provision the resources needed to operate in the country where you want to send SMS messages."